# How to make a Gridview template field select the row of data?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a command field in a gridview, that as it is, works as it should.  When i select it, the row is hilighted.  However, i needed to convert this field into a template, so i could give it a ID that i could reference when using a AJAX Mobal control.  I did this, and i am able to reference it with my Ajax control just fine, but, now this field does not select the row in the Gridview?  The Select value is needed for the Ajax control to pull the data thru.  So i think my issue is, How do i use this command field as a template, AND have it select the row?  I hope i am explaining my issue correctly.
Here is the snippet of code when i convert it into a template.
Thank you!

```
   <asp:GridView ID="GridView3" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="3" DataKeyNames="Contact_ID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" PageSize="6">
         <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
             <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Select" Text="Edit"></asp:LinkButton>
                       <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender2" runat="server" TargetControlID="LinkButton1" PopupControlID="DetailsView1" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground"></asp:ModalPopupExtender>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                 </asp:TemplateField>
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="Contact_ID" HeaderText="Contact_ID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Contact_ID" Visible="False" />
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="Contact_Assigned_Username" HeaderText="Username" SortExpression="Contact_Assigned_Username" />
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="Contact_First_Name" HeaderText="First Name" SortExpression="Contact_First_Name" />
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="Contact_Last_Name" HeaderText="Last Name" SortExpression="Contact_Last_Name" />
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="Contact_Email_Address" HeaderText="Email Address" SortExpression="Contact_Email_Address" />
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="Contact_Cell_Phone" HeaderText="Cell Phone" SortExpression="Contact_Cell_Phone" />
                 <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Contact_Administrator" HeaderText="Admin" SortExpression="Contact_Administrator" />
                 <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Contact_LineStat_Triggers_Email" HeaderText="Email Triggers" SortExpression="Contact_LineStat_Triggers_Email" />
                 <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Contact_LineStat_Triggers_Text" HeaderText="Text Triggers" SortExpression="Contact_LineStat_Triggers_Text" />
                 <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Contact_Web_Portal" HeaderText="Web Access" SortExpression="Contact_Web_Portal" />
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="Contact_Customer_ID" HeaderText="Contact_Customer_ID" SortExpression="Contact_Customer_ID" Visible="False" />
              </Columns>
         <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
         <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
         <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
         <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
         <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
         <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
         <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
         <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
         <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
         <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
     </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Please make more of an effort to format your code so that it's readable next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the RowDataBound event, try something like this:

```
protected void GridView3_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton btn = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("LinkButton1");
    btn.OnClientClick = Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(GridView3, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex.ToString()));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.  Do i put this in the vb.net code behind?

Comment: Assign the OnRowDataBound event handler in the ASPX, and use this code to handle the event in the code behind. VB syntax should be fairly similar in this case.

Comment: I have not quite figured it out yet, but i appreciate your help!